# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: DELETE

Tags: laravel

He subido mi sitio web a un host gratuito en laravel 8, en local funciona correctamente, pero en el servidor no lo hace, la ruta me arroja "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: DELETE.", cambio la ruta y el "type" del ajax a get y funciona, pero no es buena practica, alguien sabe el porque sucede¿
Mi ruta.

```
Route::delete('/productos/eliminar/{id}', [ProductoController::class,'destroy'])->name('eliminar-productos');
```

controlador.

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $delete = Producto::find($id);
    
    $delete->delete();

    return response()->json(['Error'=>0,'Mensaje'=>'Borrado']);
}
```

ajax

```
function borrar(d) {
        let id = d;

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
        $.ajax({
            type: 'DELETE',
            url: 'productos/eliminar/' + id,
            success: function(response) {
                $('#example').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                console.log(response.Mensaje);
            }
        });
    }
```

Nota: Tambien me sucede con la ruta "PUT" para actualizar, cambio la ruta y el ajax a POST y funciona, he leido que quizas se deba a los cors, ya he modificado pero nada. Uso 000webhost

Comment: no entiendo por que no es buena practica decir que la ruta es para lo cual fue creada, puede ser por el tratamiento que hace el web server a las peticiones, puede que apache este restringido o extricto en los tipos enviados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en el formulario de tu `html`, en el que no estarás definiendo el tipo de manera en la que quieres mandarlo. Si no pones nada, por defecto utiliza `get`, por o que le trndrás que poner `@method('delete')` dentro de tu formulario. Ya que no has puesto el `html`, voy a representar una estructura mínima, la cual no será como la tuya, pero lo importante es que añadas **@method('delete')** dentro del formulario.

Ejemplo:

```
<form method="POST" action="/productos/eliminar/{{id}}" id="formularioEliminar">
     @csrf

     @method('delete')
          
     <input type="submit" id="eliminarFicha"  value="Eliminar">
                        
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Me da la impresión de que es un tema más del funcionamiento del Laravel que error en el código. Podría usar la técnica de [form method spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#form-method-spoofing), quedando el ajax de la siguiente forma:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'productos/eliminar/' + id,
        data: [
            "_method": "DELETE"
        ],
        success: function(response) {
            $('#example').DataTable().ajax.reload();
            console.log(response.Mensaje);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Buenas, era esto, lo intenté con los delete y los put y funcionan correctamente, gracias

Answer (score 0):

los metodos que existe son simplemente post y get, delete y put son simples input hidden que se envian a laravel

puedes hacer esto:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete" />
```

o esto:

```
@method('delete')
```